# Highlighting ListView item like youtube Application?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hi I am working on an application in which when I select on an listitem its background color should change and it should also show a vertical bar of single color at left side of listitem like it appears in youtube application.

**The image is attached below:**
[image]

I know how to change background color on listview item click but how do I add the red line which is apprearing in youtube application. For this I have thought of adding a view in listview item xml which I would make visible on item click event.But in that case how would I hide the view from other listview items? Or is their any other easy way to implement this?

Comment: Use drawable images (9 patch images)

Comment: @PankajKumar Didn't get your solution.Please elaborate

Comment: Do you know about custom selectors for list view? If yes then use images instead of using colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this drawable for item state_pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="10dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a background selector. To do that create a XML file with different drawables for different row states (selected, focused etc.). You can find many examples on how to do that. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

After that just set your row background Drawable to this file.

Comment: I know this thing but how do I add the red line through drawable?Which element ,property should I use?

Comment: What do you mean? All you need to do is just to create a Drawable (from Image) with red line.

Comment: according to you using a single drawable we can implement that red line and change the list item background color also?

Comment: You can define 3 Drawables, each for different list state :) Do you know how to do that or you need some advices?

Answer (score 0):

To create a list view of that sort you will need to create custom adapters. Creating a view with all the elements present in it. Populating list using the custom ArrayListAdapter and using background selector for the background color.

Also, for the vertical bar default view will be invisible and made visible to the selection. Create a public static list to keep the track of selection even after the view is closed.